# What are the formulas to compute the greeks of a gap option?

Tags: greeks, exotics

I'm having a problem to calculate the gap option greeks since there are 2 different exercise prices K1 and K2. Do you know the answer or where can I read about these particular greeks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long *gap call option* position is the same as long an *asset-or-nothing digital* option and short a *cash-or-nothing digital* option, both "classical".

$$ (S_T-K_1)\cdot 1_{S_T > K_2} = S_T\cdot 1_{S_T > K_2} -K_1\cdot 1_{S_T > K_2}$$

Comment: Thank you! I was able to find all the greeks in this way!

Comment: Why not list them here in an answer so we can "imparare" something also.